# Pandas merge_asof on multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes:

DF1:

```
StartDate      Location

2013-01-01     20000002
2013-03-01     20000002
2013-08-01     20000002
2013-01-01     20000003
2013-03-01     20000003
2013-05-01     20000003
2013-01-01     20000043
```

DF2:

```
EmpStartDate   Location

2012-12-17     20000002.0 
2013-02-25     20000002.0 
2013-06-26     20000002.0 
2012-09-24     20000003.0 
2013-01-07     20000003.0 
2013-07-01     20000043.0
```

I want the count from DF2 where DF1.Location = DF2.Location and DF2.EmpStartDate<=DF1.StartDate

Output:

```
StartDate      Location   Count

2013-01-01     20000002   1
2013-03-01     20000002   2
2013-08-01     20000002   3
2013-01-01     20000003   1
2013-03-01     20000003   2
2013-05-01     20000003   2
2013-01-01     20000043   0
```

I am using merge_asof on DF2.EmpStartDate and DF1.StartDate and then doing a group by on Location and StartDate to achieve this.
But I am getting incorrect results as I am merging only on the date columns. I need to merge the dataframes on both Location and Date columns. Looks like merge_asof doesnt support merging on multiple columns. How do I merge the date columns on different groups of location?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`merge_asof` maintains the size of the `left` DataFrame, so it cannot match the same row in `left` to multiple rows in `right`.

A simple, but perhaps memory inefficient way to calculate this is to perform one big `merge` on `Location` and then count how many rows have `df.EmpStartDate < df.StartDate`

```
df = df1.merge(df2)
(df.assign(Count = df.EmpStartDate < df.StartDate)
   .groupby(['StartDate', 'Location'])
   .Count.sum()
   .astype('int')
   .reset_index())
```

#### Output:

```
   StartDate  Location  Count
0 2013-01-01  20000002      1
1 2013-01-01  20000003      1
2 2013-01-01  20000043      0
3 2013-03-01  20000002      2
4 2013-03-01  20000003      2
5 2013-05-01  20000003      2
6 2013-08-01  20000002      3
```

Comment: "`merge_asof` is only capable of producing a 1:1 merge, so I don't think that's what you want here." -- What makes you say this? There's many instances where the operation can use the same data for multiple rows in your 'left' dataframe?

Answer (score 2):

Let use this:

```
df1.merge(df2, on='Location')\
   .query('EmpStartDate <= StartDate')\
   .groupby(['StartDate','Location'])['EmpStartDate']\
   .count()\
   .reindex(df1, fill_value=0)\
   .rename('Count')\
   .reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   StartDate  Location  Count
0 2013-01-01  20000002      1
1 2013-03-01  20000002      2
2 2013-08-01  20000002      3
3 2013-01-01  20000003      1
4 2013-03-01  20000003      2
5 2013-05-01  20000003      2
6 2013-01-01  20000043      0
```

Comment: I am getting the counts as 0 with reindex.

Comment: Yes, those are missing dates and locations, filling the value with 0.  If you don't want that then you can remove the 'fill_value' parameter from re-index.

Comment: I mean the entire result set is coming as 0! If I remove the reindex I am getting proper results. But, I will have to handle it in case of any missing values..

Comment: I am not understanding.   If you remove reindex you get the proper results? To get missing location/dates, you need to generate a list of all possible locations and dates, then use re-index.

Comment: Yes, if I remove reindex I am getting proper results. If I include reindex the counts are coming as 0 for all the rows. Currently there are no missing locations or dates in the data. So, I guess it is reindexing all the rows. But, the data may vary every month. So, I will have to handle it and write a generalized code.